# Combine element type with ID

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have several tables in one HTML. I would like to set style for each table separately. I've tried this, it's working for `table` element, but it's not working for `td` and `th` elements (I would also like to apply rule `tr:nth-child(even)` only for table `#pisani` :

```css
#pisani {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
td#pisani {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th#pisani {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="pisani">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your selector is wrong. Use `#pisani td`. CSS selector works in `.parnet .child` format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `#pisani tr` which means like all tr's inside `#pisani`

```css
#pisani {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#pisani td{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

 #pisani th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}



 #pisani tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
 <table id="pisani">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some bugs on your css usage. please see the below code, it may help you

```css
#pisani {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

#pisani td{
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

 #pisani th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}



 tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="pisani">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are just using wrong selectors. Use selectors in `parent to child` format.

For more info about [CSS Selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

```css
#pisani {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#pisani td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
#pisani th{
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
#pisani tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="pisani">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you should do something like this

You are doing it as td#pisani ,it means you are looking for td with id pisani,which is wrong.you should change it as #pisani tr,td,th (within pisani it is looking for tr,td and th)

```css
#pisani {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
#pisani tr,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
#pisani tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}
```

```html
<table id="pisani">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope it helps